# How can you limit the maximum number of tags an object can have in django-taggit?

Tags: python, django, tags, django-taggit

I've been really impressed with the implementation of django-taggit as an application for handling tags within Django. However, I have been unable to find a way to set a maximum number  of tags which can be applied to an object - a 'MAX_TAG' if you will. Is this possible? I'd like to limit my application to, for example, only 5 tags per object.

Thanks,

J

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved this in the admin model:

```
class MyObjectAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def clean_tags(self):
        tags = self.cleaned_data['tags']
        if len(tags) > 3:
            raise ValidationError("....")
        return tags

class MyObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyObjectAdminForm
```

Comment: Oh thats pretty tidy! Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

The TaggableManager uses an internal [_TaggableManager](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/master/taggit/managers.py#L143) that has an `add` method that you'll need to change.

First, you'll need to extend `_TaggableManager` and change the `add` method to check how many tags are being used, and modify the list of tags accordingly.

Then you'll have to extend `TaggableMananger` and override `__get__` so that it uses your custom `_TaggableManager`.